# How do I return a pointer to a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a template class in C++ that looks like this:

```
template <typename T, int xMax, int yMax, int zMax>
class Volume {
public:
    T*[64][64] getDataPointer() {return data;} //compiler doesn't like this line
private:
    T data[xMax][yMax][zMax];
};

typedef Volume<unsigned char, 64, 64, 64> Chunk;
```

The compiler doesn't like the return I have for getDataPointer().  I want to return the same type I would then use to pass to this function:

```
void perlin2D(unsigned char (*chunk)[64][64])
```

Can someone show me how to do that?

Comment: You should probably use `xMax`, `yMax` and `zMax` instead of hardcoding `64` into the return type. Also, C doesn't have templates, so I removed the C tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the signature to :

```
T (*getDataPointer())[64][64] {return data;}
```

Answer (score -1):

T*** getDataPointer() {return data;}
maybe you need something like this?